# What problems will occur when event are sudden increased to too high like 10 times in spark streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Actually Someone asked this question in an interview. And I want to know what answer should be there or what type of explanation should be there which can satisfy the interviewer. The question was that How will you handle spark streaming application which is processing 10 Million records if sudden records will be increased three times. What changes need to do in your spark application?

Comment: Thanks Robert,Actually I have given the answer like I have told them first I will check if partitioning is correct in the events,I can increase the number of executor on the basis of time in I want to process the events.I can increase the number of brokers in kafka so it can increase the parallelism.Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I have no idea.  I'm not a spark expert.

Comment: Spark spills events to disk if they don't fit it memory, but what's wrong about adding executors and/or memory?

Comment: I think he wanted me to explain about backpressure algo and dynamic allowcation to handle sudden spikes in input traffic.